# How to check the thread safe functions?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I have found out that `tst_brkm()` is not thread safe. But I don't how to check. What are the steps and tools to check that my function is thread safe or not?

Comment: Via documentation is the only method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads share the heap, but have their own private stack space. What this means is that each thread has its own view of local variables, but any data in the heap can be overwritten if you don't synchronize with mutexes/semaphores. So the first question to ask yourself is: What are the memory addresses I'm accessing and will a single thread have it's own view of the resources that the addresses point to?